# cant create filters in django project

Tags: python, django, filter, django-rest-framework, pycharm

i want add filter in the project but this error comes to me in CMD

```
AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.filters' has no attribute 'DjangoFilterBackend'
```

the Project Name = frame
the ProjectApp Name = framework

Views.py

```
from typing import Tuple
from django.shortcuts import render
from .serializer import TaskSerializers
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Task
from rest_framework import filters
import django_filters

# Create your views here.
class myviewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializers
    filter_backends =(filters.DjangoFilterBackend,filters.OrederingFilter)
    filter_fields=('completed',)
    ordering = ('-date_created')
```

Installed app:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'framework',
    'rest_framework',
    'django_filters',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DjangoFilterBackend` class does *not* originate from `rest_framework.filters`, but from the `django_filters.rest_framework` module, so you should import this as:

```
from typing import Tuple
from django.shortcuts import render
from .serializer import TaskSerializers
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Task
#     ↓ load from the django_filters module
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework import filters
import django_filters

# Create your views here.
class myviewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializers
    filter_backends =(DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter)
    filter_fields=('completed',)
    ordering = ('-date_created',)
```

In order to use this, you will first need to install the `django-filter` package in the virtual environment:

```
pip install django-filter
```

and add this to the `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # …,
    'django_filters',
    # …
]
```

Comment: now the OrderingFilter not work (((AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.filters' has no attribute 'OrederingFilter')))

Comment: @HAbdullah: that's because you made a typo. It is `OrderingFilter`, not `Ored...`.